# Django - Return remaining throttle calls available

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, throttling

I am trying to retrieve the remaining calls available with no luck, the use case is sending that data in the response or headers to the frontend, so that the end user can check the credit of API calls available

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.ScopedRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'my_view': '10/day',
    }
}
```

views.py

```
class MyView(APIView):
    throttle_classes = [ScopedRateThrottle]
    throttle_scope = 'my_view'
```